# Manually synchronize a webdav share with a local folder

Tags: nautilus, webdav

I am running Ubuntu 13.04.

I want to manually synchronize a local folder with a webdavs share.

I can type `Control-l` in Nautilus (Files), type in the `davs://user@myserver.com:port/` and mount the folder without any difficulty. I am not getting the syncing part.

Answer (score 0):

Once the webdav folder is mounted, you then need to run some sort of syncronisation. I have often used rsync for things like network device mirroring. Rsync allows you to dictate which folder has priority i.e. which direction to sync in, and allows you to add credentials although they shouldn't be needed if your Nautilus connection works ok.

The only problem you've got is that rsync is command driven and you need to find the mount point of your webdav folder for the command string. I've got nautilus-open-terminal installed so I can right-click in a folder in Nautilus and open the terminal in that location. Seems to be the easiest way to find that mount point.